# Keep getting expected primary-expression befor 'minflightNumber' and 'maxflightNumber'... Not sure what to do

Tags: c++

```
int maxdelay(int max, int delay, string flightNumber)
{
    if (max < delay)
    {
        max = delay;
        flightNumber = string maxflightNumber;
    }
    else
        max = max;
    return max;
}
int mindelay(int min, int delay, string flightNumber)
{

    if (min > delay)
    {
        min = delay;
        flightNumber = string minflightNumber;
    }
    else
        min = min;
    return min;
}
```

Keep getting expected primary-expression before 'minflightNumber' and 'maxflightNumber'... Not sure what to do.

Comment: What do you intend `string` to do? - it's not valid.

Comment: You may have problems with this if you do the bad habit of adding `using namespace std;` to your code.

Comment: I think you wanted `flightNumber =  std::to_string(maxflightNumber);` although where is `maxflightNumber` coming from?

Comment: And what is the purpose of the `flightNumber` parameter? There is not enough context to determine what the intention of this code is. And the bugs aren't  helping..

Comment: `min = min` doesn't accomplish anything. If you don't want the `else` to do anything, you can remove it.